# NullPointerException on Fragment Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

The declaration of the array.

```
public ExerciseFragment[] fragments;
```

The initialization.

```
fragments = new ExerciseFragment[numberOfWorkouts];
```

And finally, setting each fragment equal to it's respective `ExerciseFragment`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkouts; i++) {
        ft.add(LinearLayoutID, new ExerciseFragment(), "KEY"+i);
        fragments[i] = (ExerciseFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("KEY"+i);
    }
```

whyn trying to access fragments[] I always get a NullPointerException and I have searched and searched with no luck, I can't find where I went wrong, hopefully some fresh eyes can!

Comment: Can you show the LogCat output? It usually points to the line on which the NPE occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing it to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkouts; i++) {
    fragments[i] = new ExerciseFragment();
    ft.add(LinearLayoutID, fragments[i], "KEY"+i);
}
```

Does that still give an error message when you run that?

I'm thinking that getFragmentManager() might be returning null in your question. Since I can't see the code for getFragmentManager, declaration and assignment for ft, and findFragmentByTag, so I can't be sure.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, sometimes I code things and I just can't seem to see the light, always helpful to have another set of eyes. Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly!